# What input voltages does the 85W Magsafe 2 power adapter accept?

Tags: charging, power, magsafe

I have an [85W Magsafe 2 (A1242, MD506LL) power adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD506LL/A/apple-85w-magsafe-2-power-adapter-for-macbook-pro-with-retina-display) which has been happily driving my MacBook Pro from US and Canadian 110V AC power. I am about to take this power adapter to Europe. Will I be able to plug this adapter into a plug adapter (from [North American type B socket](https://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeB.htm) to [Europlug type C plug](https://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeC.htm)), which passes through mains voltage and frequency unchanged, and plug that into normal outlets in Italy, Austria, Croatia, and the UK ([type G plug](https://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeG.htm) for the UK of course) and have it operate correctly?

What input voltages and frequencies does the 85W Magsafe 2 power adapter accept?

I have been unable to find definitive specs on the adapter itself or on Apple's website. I would hope the answer is "110-240V 50/60Hz", as it is for my cheap USB power bricks, but I'm not going to plug in my expensive MacBook Pro based on hope. I'd appreciate pointers to definitive information.

Comment: Different countries have different shaped plugs if this is what you’re asking. The voltage accepted by an electric device is written on said electric device - by law. On mac adapters it’s written on the side. They are all dual voltage so you can use 240 or 110 and just change the country specific plug shape depending on your location.

Comment: @MicroMachine where were you in August 2019? You could have answered this question for me, instead of me having to wait for https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366537/17600 . "It's written on the side" is the responsive answer. Plugs are not a factor, the question clearly says "Will I be able to plug this adapter into a plug adapter" and have it work. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: “Will I be able to plug (etc) is asked in the first paragraph. There is afterwards another paragraph containing a question. And your question doesn’t end with a clear question (no “?” In the last paragraph). For that formatting problem alone I could downvote...

Comment: If you think it will improve the site, you should downvote. If you are trying to get payback because your answer got downvoted, you should not. I observe that the first two paragraphs ask the same question in a slightly different way, and both end with a question mark. The third paragraph provides context. I think it's a reasonably-worded question. But by posting on this site, we all open our work up for evaluation.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about how the site works. In the past, I have deleted my questions that had 0 upvotes even if they didn’t get downvotes. No point in keeping something useless around. And I don’t downvote because I think it’s a dick move, unless if it’s spam or extremely mediocre. Sanctioning doesn’t work on humans, cf data. If I did however downvote, I would downvote most of your content, which is confusingly written, badly worded, duplicates of already existing questions, and way too long and never clear or illustrated. To each his own. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Input: 100-240V~ 1.5A 50-60 Hz Output:20V [DC] 4.25A max"

The answer is in fact on the side of the adapter. There is text on the plug end and on one of the narrow sides of the adapter. The input information is on the narrow side, in low-contrast light-grey fine print on a white background (thank you, Apple). With a light and a magnifier, my old eyes were finally able to make it out.

"[DC]" refers to a symbol with a solid line next to a dashed line, meaning "direct current".