# Using europlug adapter from Mag Safe 2 with the usb-c charger (US version)

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

Can I use the europlug adapter from Mag Safe 2 with the usb-c charger (US version) to charge my MacBook pro 14?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What input voltages does the 85W Magsafe 2 power adapter accept?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366535/what-input-voltages-does-the-85w-magsafe-2-power-adapter-accept)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the actual interchangeable plug that connects to the 'brick:

[image]

then yes, that will work with anything that it can physically connect to. There aren't different models of plug for all the different power cables that Apple has made.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether its one of the interchangeable plugs or just a regular 'tourist adaptor'.